# Having trouble starting an activity from Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity

I have a MapFragment in my app. As soon as the Map is loaded, I am ploting certain markers. Next, i want to create a new FragmentActivity when the user touches one of the markers. For which, I have used the setOnMarkerClickListener() as shown,

```
gmap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AdaptorMain.class));
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I am getting the following error:

```
The constructor Intent(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener(){}, Class<AdaptorMain>) is undefined
```

I have registered the activity in the Manifest file.

Comment: when you are using "this" it thinks you are referencing the onMarkerClickListener and it wants the application context, try to use "getApplicationContext()"

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the Activity's context instead of that of the OnMarkerClickListener.

```
 gmap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(MyCurrentActivity.this, AdaptorMain.class));
            return false;
        }
    });
```